# Route Enhancer for sf_event_mgt

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

I can't get the list route enhancer working for [sf_event_mgt 5.0.1](https://github.com/derhansen/sf_event_mgt/tree/5.0.1) in my TYPO3 10.4.6 installation. All the other routes seem to work (detail, registration etc.) but list, instead of just linking the list plugin page, generates a link to

```
/veranstaltungen-1?tx_sfeventmgt_pievent%5Baction%5D=list&tx_sfeventmgt_pievent%5Bcontroller%5D=Event&cHash=19b6ef72f7fdbb2f7bc9269ab3ea3446
```

I'm using the exact configuration provided in the [extension documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/derhansen/sf_event_mgt/master/en-us/ForAdministrators/Configuration/RouteEnhancers/Index.html). (except for the page uids of course)

I've also tried adding a plugin route enhancer just for the list action like [tx_news](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/master/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html#basic-setup-including-categories-and-tags) used to do, and change the list route to something else than "/" but to no avail.

```yaml
EventList:
    type: Plugin
    routePath: '/{@widget_0/currentPage}'
    namespace: tx_sfeventmgt_pievent
     aspects:
      '@widget_0/currentPage':
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '1000'
```

as part of the sf_event_mgt config from the documentation:

```yaml
…
routes:
      - { routePath: '/list/{page}', _controller: 'Event::list', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'}  }
…
```

I didn't bother to check if the argument target is correct here, since the route doesn't work anyway, even without any arguments.

In contrast the route configuration for news works like a charm

```yaml
NewsList:
    type: Plugin
    routePath: '/{@widget_0/currentPage}'
    namespace: tx_news_pi1
    aspects:
      '@widget_0/currentPage':
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '1000'
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of sf_event_mgt. I think there might be a problem with you routing configuration, since you define the key of the page aspect to be as `@widget_0/currentPage` (which includes a slash).

The following configuration should work as expected with the latest version of the extension on TYPO3 10.4.6:

```
EventPlugin:
  type: Extbase
  limitToPages: [3,4,5]
  extension: SfEventMgt
  plugin: Pievent
  routes:
    - { routePath: '/{page}', _controller: 'Event::list', _arguments: {page: '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
  defaultController: 'Event::list'
  defaults:
    page: '1'
  requirements:
    page: '\d+'
  aspects:
    page:
      type: StaticRangeMapper
      start: '1'
      end: '100'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time! Indeed adding the page parameter and an aspect mapper seems to have done the trick and now I only get the path to the page when linking the list action. Weirdly the example list route from the documentation still appends all the extbase parameters described above.

Comment: If my answer resolves your problem, please mark it as accepted. If you believe the example in the documentation is wrong, feel free to add an issue on the project page of sf_event_mgt on GitHub

Comment: I haven't really looked inside the core too much, so I can't really say if the example should even be changed. So far it seems like I'm the only one that had this specific problem.